# How to compute an histogram (plot bars) binning the values from a .csv using TeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, csv

I've a `.csv` with a column of acquired **measures**. I would like to make the histogram bins using TeX from the **measures distribution** so I have to create the bins first. I haven't found any reference to perform an automatic binning or to set manually the intervals to produce the bins. I would like to know how can I do that and if I can perform [non-uniform bins histogram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55777/histogram-with-uniform-vs-non-uniform-bins).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
dist
1
2
2.5
2
1
3.5
3
1
3
2
1
1
0.5
1
1.5
1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}
\addplot[xbar] table [
        col sep=comma,
        x=dist
    ] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [ybar interval] table [
        col sep=comma,
        y=dist
    ] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I perform this usually in python (code below) this should be the output:
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dist=[1, 2, 2.5, 2, 1, 3.5, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 1]
plt.hist(dist,7) #Compute the histogram of a set of data.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the PGFPlots `statistics` library for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
dist
1
2
2.5
2
1
3.5
3
1
3
2
1
1
0.5
1
1.5
1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0
]
\addplot +[
    hist={
        bins=7,
        data min=0.5,
        data max=4
    }   
] table [y index=0] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I put the data in an external file data.csv? Your example works for me, but the histogram is blank, when I try to implement it.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: Yes, you can use an external file. Actually, that's the real way you would do it, the `filecontents` approach used in my answer is just to make copying and pasting the example easier.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! I got a "No room for new \write" error message otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Here, have some `gnuplot`. Using the `gnuplottex` package, typeset using `pdflatex --shell-escape`:

## Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
1
2
2.5
2
1
3.5
3
1
3
2
1
1
0.5
1
1.5
1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex,terminaloptions={pdf color}]
    set xrange [0:4]
    set yrange [0:8]
    set style fill solid 1
    plot 'data.csv' using 1:(1) smooth frequency with boxes title 'Data'
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: I finally got gnuplot inside tex working, based on your sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [`pst-plot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\savedata{\data}[{{0.5,1},{1,7},{1.5,1},{2,3},{2.5,1},{3,2},{3.5,1}}]

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit = 2}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.23,-0.53)(4,7.5)
\listplot[
  plotstyle = bar,
  barwidth = 0.8,
  linecolor = red,
  fillstyle = solid,
  fillcolor = blue!70
]{\data}
\psaxes[
  Dx = 0.5,
  xticksize = -4pt 0
]{->}(4,7.5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

P.S. I can't figure out exactly what the data are, but from your plot I've guessed. If I'm wrong, you should be able to change it yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry I've saw only now that although the plotted data result is right the way in which is achieve is not what I was asking. The goal of my question is to perform the binning with TeX (See the Jake answer or the analogous Python code) not to plot an histogram with pre-computed bins.  Thanks however for the help!

Comment: Beware, however, that this is not a histogram, but a bar plot.

Answer (score 1):

Although is not a pure LaTeX approarch, may be an alternative to someone could be a Sweave (`.Rnw`) file, that R can convert in a true `.tex` file.

With a well configured LaTeX editor as TeXworks, or RStudio  this is not extra work for the user, as you simply  edit the `.Rnw` file an the PDF file is compiled with one click, without dealing with R nor intermediate LaTeX files.

With this approach is easy make non-uniform bins histograms (with option `breaks` in the R plot) and set the x-axis range (option `xlim`):

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

Automatic breaks with range fixed:

<<examplea,echo=F,fig=T,height=3>>=
sample <- read.table("data.csv", header=TRUE, sep="", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
hist(sample$X1, xlim=c(0,4), main="",xlab="", ylab="", col="orange")

@

Manual uneven breaks:

<<exampleb,echo=F,fig=T,height=3>>=
hist(sample$X1, breaks=c(0.5,1,1.5,3.5),freq=T, main="",xlab="", ylab="", col="cyan")
@

Automatic fixed breaks at these values:

<<examplec,echo=F,fig=T,height=3>>=
mybreaks <- as.vector(exp(seq(log(.01),log(6),by=0.5)))
mybreaks
hist(sample$X1, breaks=mybreaks, freq=T,main="",xlab="", ylab="", col="red")
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 thanks! I think maybe this is better regarding performance! the performance of the pure tex version are not so good (is quite slow) and so if someone have big data file he should use this alternative!