# Tikz | How to change line color of histogram

Tags: pgfplots, color, histogram

I am trying to follow this answer for drawing a [historgram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153328/103849). I was able to change the fill color of the histogram but I was not able to change the line color of the bars.

> **Question**: What do I have to modify to have black outlines for the bars.

Just for reference (this is the code provided by @Jake)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
dist
1
2
2.5
2
1
3.5
3
1
3
2
1
1
0.5
1
1.5
1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0
]
\addplot +[
    hist={
        bins=7,
        data min=0.5,
        data max=4
    }   
] table [y index=0] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `draw=black` to the `\addplot` options.