# Brickbating a Histogram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I approximately learn how we can plot a histogram by help of [here manual](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153325/how-to-compute-an-histogram-plot-bars-binning-the-values-from-a-csv-using-tex). But I do not know how can I plot a histogram as a collection of *brickbats* as below shape:

[image: brickbat histogram]

Comment: OT: I don't think [brickbat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brickbat) means what you think it does...

Comment: (-1) for no MWE. Please note that this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need more than this, but you did not show it:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw[<-] (6,0) node[below] {?} -- (-.5,0);
\draw[->] (0,-.5) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};
\draw (0,0) grid (5,1) (2,1) grid (3,4) (4,1) rectangle (5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. I am learning how can I generalize that. I have problem with "\draw (0,0) grid (5,1) (2,1) grid (3,4) (4,1) rectangle (5,2)" but I am thinking about their parameters

Comment: @Irreversible They are simply coordinates, nothing more. What is your problem?

Comment: You are right. When two pairs brought together same as (3,4) (4,1) I could not understand the mean of that. Right now I can understand. They are separated. "(2,1) grid (3,4)" are related to each other and "(0,0) grid (5,1)" also with each other.